# Laravel 5.8 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::fire()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I get this error on user registration. I have searched for this problem a lot and still couldn't solve the problem on my side. In laravel 5.8 upgrade, it's written that function `fire()` is changed to `dispatch()`, but I can't find any `fire()` function in any file of my app, so I can see what's happening.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide us with some code so we can work out what the actual problem is, we cannot do this with just a description.

Comment: Hello Hovhannes, as an advice, I suggest you to check this guide in order to make a clear and complete question: [ask]

Comment: https://ibb.co/KmtLLQ1
Here is a snippet from my RegisterController, just a regular registration stuff is going on, nothing strange. I started to get this error after laravel upgrade from 5.6 to 5.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events#dispatching-events

Instead of:

```php
Event::fire(new \App\Events\NewUserSignup($new_user));
```

Do instead:

```php
event(new \App\Events\NewUserSignup($new_user));
```

Answer (score 0):

The fire method (which was deprecated in Laravel 5.4) of the Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher class has been removed(https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26392). You should use the dispatch method instead.

Instead of:
`Event::dispatch('customer.created', $customer);`

Do this:
`Event::dispatch('customer.created', $customer);`

OR:
`event('customer.created', $customer);`